# Hide my app contacts from user

Tags: android, contacts, private

I want to use the contacts API but for my specific application my users will most likely not want these contacts polluting their contact list. The application is targeted for delivery drivers and I want to use Contacts to keep track of past deliveries. I don't really care if the user can edit or change the contacts, but I don't want to confuse the user by having these contacts start populating in their address book.

Any ideas? Otherwise I will use a SQLite Database but I hate re-inventing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contact list allows you to set the "is visible group" setting.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#IN_VISIBLE_GROUP

While you shouln't use this just because you are too lazy to write your own content provider, it is useful for some apps that you can save contacts in and don't want to annoy users with...  (I think a number of apps do this, possibly Facebook at times?)

You can simply set that flag when you insert the contact in the contacts content provider by setting the appropriate flags.

Comment: Contentprovider is not necessary in this context, since he doesn't want to share them.

Comment: It's true a content provider wouldn't be necessary, but there's no reason he wouldn't want to write one for his own (internal) app use, and if he ever had any reason to share them, this would allow extension.  So I think saying that writing a content provider is _inappropriate_ is probably misguided, at the very least it would allow him to abstract the implementation.

Comment: point noted, its just another approach. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Regardless of whether or not it is the correct approach for my situation, this is the information I needed. Also, why should I write my own content provider for something available already built into the platform? I figured the opposite would be true, and that doing it myself would be a case of re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store your own contact to another database...? Ideally in your application.

Comment: An entirely feasible option. I would just rather avoid it if the Contacts API can do what I want. I try to make use of what is available to the platform as much as possible.